# Apache mod_rewrite for uri with no extension

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, mode

I need help with apache url rewrite,I want all urls with no extension to be redirected to index.php?id=query_string.

`http://www.abc.com/abc` it should go to `http://www.abc.com/index.php?id=abc`

for links with extensions it should not disturb

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is what you're looking for, but here's my go at it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule     ^[!/.]*([A-Za-z]+)/?$       /index.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

If the URL does not contain a '.' character and it contains just letters it puts it in the 'id' request, else it leaves it unchanged

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it does not work when any integer comes inside

Comment: Nice to see it didn't take more than 3 minutes to add [0-9] to the rule :D.